# Photos moved to trash still displayed in Photos App

Tags: macbook-pro, photos.app

I have moved my pictures manually(by right clicking) to trash. But they are still being shown in Photos app, Why and how to delete them?

Comment: Delete them from Photos, like you're supposed to. It will complain, but it should work.

Comment: It could be a cache...

Comment: If you deleted them in Photos on your Mac, it will take some time for that change to reflected in the Photos app on your iOS device.  This happens after the next iCloud sync.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just right-clicking photos within Finder and selecting Move to Trash, this is only going to affect those particular files. For example, if you're doing that to JPEGs etc in your Pictures folder, you're only moving/trashing those files.

The Photos app (and iPhoto before it) store all imported pictures in a library. You can't delete these manually outside of the app (at least not without showing package contents and causing a whole heap of issues with metadata, etc). Instead you need to delete the photo(s) from within the Photos app.

To do this:

- Within the Photos app select the photos you want to delete. (You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click or <kbd>Command</kbd> + click to select multiple photos)
- Right-click on any of the selected photos
- You can choose to delete the photos (or even hide them if that's all you really want to do)

**NOTE:** When you *delete* a photo it actually places it in the Recently Deleted trash can (appears above your albums). The photos will remain there until you choose to recover them, or until they are automatically deleted after 30 days. You can, however, choose to go in and manually delete them from there anytime prior to the 30 day period.

Comment: if I do rm -rf * in home directory then would these pictures in photos app be deleted automatically ?

Comment: @user1718009 That would be a highly risky thing to do, especially since there are a number of factors that could impact what actually happens. Why do I now get the feeling that your question doesn't _really_ get to what you're trying to do? Perhaps there are other solutions that will work better if we understood what you really want to achieve? After all, if all you want to do is delete some photos, why wouldn't you just use the Photos app? If you're trying to remove **all** photos, then create a new Photos Library instead and just delete the old one. If it's something else, please clarify...

Comment: I have done rm -rf * in the home directory under my username and sold the laptop, I want to know that any photo existing there would have been deleted or not?

Comment: @user1718009 First of all, welcome to Ask Different (I see you're a new user). Secondly, can I strongly recommend (for your own benefit) that in future when asking a question you clarify why you're asking or what you're really trying to do. Had I known you were selling your laptop I would have given you a totally different answer. In summary, when selling a Mac you should (1) ensure you have a backup of all your data (I assume you've done this), (2) sign out of any of Apple's services (iTunes, iCloud, iMessage), and (3) reformat your hard drive and reinstall the OS.

Comment: That third one would have dealt with the whole issue of deleting your old photos. If you still have your MacBook, then refer to [What to do before selling or giving away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065) so you can be sure to have prepared your Mac correctly prior to handing it over. Hope this helps and all the best.

Comment: I am sorry for that, but I have already sold this macbook pro , what I did was
first in home directory rm -rf *, then in disk utility erased everything then I was not able to boot again and it started with flashing question mark sign, Now I am worried that If all my pictures as files and in photos app have been deleted or not?

Comment: Without knowing _exactly_ what you did, if the OS was reinstalled (whether by you or the person you sold it to), it will have absolutely no idea of any data you previously had on your drive. Now, depending on how the OS was installed (formatting the drive, etc) it's _possible_ that someone with the right data recovery software and who is very determined, could recover some of your photos. The risk of that reduces over time. Also, unless they had _reason_ to, why would they go to all the trouble involved in trying to recover the photos? I'd say you can relax.

Comment: My question is simple that without a data recovery tool, just doing a rm -rf * in home directory does delete all the content whether in photos app or files outside? And after doing that pressing CMD + R and opening disk utility and erasing all the disks shown in the left pane. 
After doing all this I was not able to reboot so the disk erasing did apply on the same time or it happens after reboot and as I was not able to reboot, I am worried if data is still there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've already answered your question. But, let me explain it another way. When you booted with CMD+R and then used Disk Utility to erase the drive, this will have got rid of any _record_ of your files having ever existed on the drive. The new owner will **not** _see_ these files after installing an OS. Now, if the new owner wanted to use data recovery software for hours (more likely a couple of days) to try and recover what data was on the drive previously, they could. Whether they are ultimately successful depends on _how_ you originally erased the drive in Disk Utility.

Comment: The fact that you used `rm -rf *` _prior_ to erasing the drive with Disk Utility is irrelevant. What is more relevant is how you erased the drive in Disk Utility. If you used a _secure erase_ option then the risk of someone being able to recover your data ranges from extremely low to impossible (depending on the setting you used).

Comment: Why is rm -rf * in home directory irrelevant? I did not see in any secure option there . I am not concerned about recovery of the files by any data recovery software,  what I am concerned about is that after reinstalling the OS would there be any files present or not?

Comment: 1. It's irrelevant because you've since erased the drive with Disk Utility. 2. As stated previously, there is no _record_ of your files having ever existed and the new owner will not see these files. 3. In summary, since you're not concerned about recovery of the files, then you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you've actually emptied trash. Next, as @Tetsujin said in the comments, make sure to delete them from Photos (inside the app), can be done on any device and on the next Cloud sync you should see them disappear from iOS and MacOS/OS X devices as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It appears you just took what was said in the comments and made them an answer.  While this isn't against any of the site 'rules', it would probably be good for you to add supporting info (i.e. text from Apple Support pages, personal experiences, etc.) to show your answer will fix the OP's problem.  - From Review